# How to set timer for database RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I just have a database in RDS, I just need to turn off it at 8:00 PM and turn on it at 8:00 AM!

Right now I do it like manually and I just need to make it dynamic!

Is there any service or specific config that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup [Schedule expressions for Amazon EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-schedule-expressions.html) which will trigger a [lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) every day at 8am and 8pm. Your function will need to have [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) to interact with RDS and use AWS SDK to automatically stop/start the db instance of your choosing.

Comment: In this way, I have to have control of the source code, right?  I just ask this question because I do not have control of the source code because I just provide this database to someone for an amount of money and he just connects to it. that is why I need to turn off at a specific time! hope you get me :)

Comment: @sime Then, you have to tell who ever controls this RDS to its account to do what I wrote.

Comment: I'm controlling the RDS now! my question was, is there anything from what you wrote I have to make or change something to the code! or just all that you said controlled from AWS no need for the code that runs this database? this is my core question :)